# Delete Nested Reference in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete a 2 levels deep nested Reference in Firestore. My Schema looks like this:

[image]

In Code it looks like this:

```
{
    "folder": "bla",
    "title": "myTitle",
    "children": [
        {
            "ref": "firstReference"
        },
        {
            "ref": "secondReference"
        },
        {
            "title": "Subcollection Title",
            "children": [
                {
                    "ref": "thirdReference"
                },
                {
                    "ref": "forthReference"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i am searching a way to remove the third or forth Reference from the second children array.

To remove an item from the first children array is use this code:

```
docRef.update({children: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(folder.children[index])
```

But this solution works only for the top level ;(

Does somebody know how to remove deeper Nested elements?

I tried:

```
docRef.update({[`children[${index}].children`]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(
                    folder.children[index].children[secondIndex])});
```

But it throws an Error (Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']')

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 2):

Firestore does not support modifying array items by index. `FieldValue.arrayRemove` only works if you pass the *exact contents* of the data to remove from an array field.  If you only know the index, then what you'll have to do is read the document, modify the array in memory, then write the new document contents back.

Comment: Yes i know, but this `folder.children[index].children[secondIndex]` is the exact content at this place. But the idea modifying it in memory came to me as well two hours later ;) Thank you ;)